# Ubuntu 16.04 : Libreoffice : Fontconfig error: failed reading config file

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

Libreoffice stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04 ! I get this error :

> Fontconfig error: failed reading config file
>
> ```
> Application Error
> ```

Please any idea about this ? thanks!

Comment: Did you do anything with font configuration before it happened?

Comment: No ! but I have installed some packages, after that it stops working, I had libreoffice 5, I removed it and installed Libreoffice 6, but still not working